# Bootstrap 3, insert a div after a line of products

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have fluid list of products:

```
<div class="row" id="myList">
    <div class="item col-md-3">Product1</div>       
    <div class="item col-md-3">Product2</div>   
    <div class="item col-md-3">Product3</div>   
    <div class="item col-md-3">Product4</div>
    <div class="item col-md-3">Product5</div>
</div>
```

I obtain a list of product with 4 product per row.
Now.. i need to insert a div after each row, but i donno how many product there are per row because in the desktop view I have 4 products in a row, while in the mobile view I have 2 products per row.

There is a solution to insert a div via javascript after each row of products?

Answer (score 1):

i am not sure if this is what you want.. but considering

> solution to insert a div via javascript after each row of products

use after.

```
 $('.item').after($('<div />'));
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xw5hC/) for you to try

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to do this dynamically, you can do it simple like:

```
$('.row').each(function() {
    $(this).after('<div class="added">whatever you want here</div>');
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Q5mXA/1/